# How can I expose my C# for scripts (e.g. VBScript) to interact with it? (Currently using SendKeys but this is causing some issues)

Tags: c#, vbscript, scripting

**Problem Background**

I am updating a well-used tool in C# which has the requirement that scripts must be able to perform certain functions automatically (hit buttons, populate text fields). To date, this has been done using `SendKeys` and `Alt` shortcuts.

However, there seem to be a variety of problems with this approach.

Errors in capitalization when the scripts are written can cause problems. Shortcuts to form elements on a Tab Control do not work if the user is on a different Tab Control.

---

**Solution Requirements**

I need scripts (for now just VBScript, but an ideal solution would work for a variety of scripting languages) to be able to achieve the following reliably -

- Click `Button`s
- Click `ToolStripMenuItem`s
- Modify the value of a `TextBox`
- Increment the value of `NumericUpDown` controls

---

**Previous (Unacceptable) Solution**

So far, to achieve the first three, <kbd>Alt</kbd> keyboard shortcuts have been created in the C# application and `SendKeys` has been used in the VBS in order to activate them. This has worked reasonably well, but unreliably (as described above).

---

This is a sample script which would set the focus to the application, use an <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcut to select the comments field and then populate it with "My Comment", before setting the focus back to the application which called the script.

```
dim ObjShell

    set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

        objShell.AppActivate "MyApplication"

        objShell.SendKeys("%{C}") 

        objShell.SendKeys("{END}")

        objShell.SendKeys("My Comment")

        objShell.AppActivate "CallingApplication"

    set objShell = Nothing
```

---

In order to do the latter, I have created 'invisible' buttons that, when 'clicked' (using another <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcut), increment the value of a `NumericUpDown`. Obviously this is a very, very bad approach, as a user could click these buttons by accident (not to mention what a clumsy, awkward workaround it is!).

---

I am sure there must be a better way, but so far I've had no luck finding it...

To make it clear -

- I have full control over the C# Application
- I have full control over the scripts
- I only have control over the application calling the scripts to the extent that I can determine what scripts it runs

Comment: In what application are those Buttons etc. located? Does that application have an API or can it be called from the command prompt? If neither, then I'm afraid there is no alternative to `SendKeys`.

Comment: The `Buttons` etc. are located in the C# application which is fully under my control. I just have no idea of any alternatives to `SendKeys` - I will happily implement anything reliable! 

I have control over the C# application and the scripts themselves (which for now must be VBScript but others are possible in the future). I do not have control over the application calling the scripts beyond which scripts it calls.

Comment: You control the C# program. You control the scripts that interact with it. (Just not the application that calls these scripts.) Okay, so perhaps you can expose your C# program via an API, and have the scripts call that API. I know this can be done, but I'm not familiar enough with it to help with how. However, I can tell you that this is what you should ask about. Currently your question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript (and other scripting tools) can instantiate COM visible objects.

So, create a new project in the solution and mark it COM visible. [Walkthrough: Creating a simple component in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779077.aspx)

Add a class (i.e. MyAppController or some such name) to the project for the script to create and interact with.

Place the logic for controlling and updating the application in the MyAppController class with well defined public methods.

Sample Script

```
 Set app = CreateObject("MyAppController")
 app.AddComment("My new Comment")
```

To get the MyAppController class to talk with your app you will need to setup a simple interprocess communications link. Something like Named Pipes will work well MSDN: [How to: Use Named Pipes for Interprocess Communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx)

This should simplify your scripts and make the communication much more robust. For example there is no need to swap the active process back and forth to update the comment.